# Alternative algorithms for calculating x^2?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I'm emulating 128-bit arithmetic. At the moment I'm calculating $x^2$ by computing $x\cdot x$. What might be some alternative methods that aren't simply dressing up multiplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on the fact that:

If n is an even number $(n = 2m) \implies n^2 = 4m^2$

If n is an odd number $(n = 2m + 1) \implies n^2 = 4m^2 + 4m + 1$

And you can calculate $m$ by bitwise shifting right of $n$, calculate $4m$ (or $4m^2$) by bitwise shifting left.

So you can apply the recursion method to this process to establish the result with $O(\log n)$ time complexity.

Comment: Nice approach, +1. I haven't thought about this before. I guess there are some optimizations (skipping the recursion once the bitwise shift causes the number to become $0$).

Comment: This needs more performance analysis like the number of additions. The transformation is fine as longs as the cost of additions is not higher the replaced multiplications as in Karatsuba.

Comment: ... where n is the number of bits in the number. For products of huge numbers you could do something similar increasing the number size by say 64 bit at a time. May be a little bit more efficient than generic multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $x^2 = \exp(2\log x)$.

However, this is probably inferior to using $x^2 = x \cdot x$ in almost all situations.

Answer (score -3):

You can simply use `pow(x,2)` this comes under the library `#include<math.h>`

Comment: Obviously if that function is implemented in any not completely brain-damaged way, then it will calculate pow(x, 2) as x*x.

Comment: This is not a programming language specific question, I do not have access to such functions.

Comment: So you should specify that while asking question

Comment: This site is for general computer science (conceptual) questions; so specifying that it is not language-specific is not necessary.

Comment: [netlib implementation](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c) is essentially $\exp(2\log x)$. No special case for $y=2$.